# How to pass a function to julia Gadfly Theme parameter

Tags: julia, gadfly

I make a plot like this:

```
plot(
  layer(x=sort(randn(1000),1), y=sort(randn(1000),1), Geom.point),
  layer(x=[-4,4], y=[-4,4], Geom.line(), Theme(default_color=color("black"))))
```

[image: ScatterPlot]

As you can see, the white circle around the points makes the high density parts of the plot almost white.

I would like to change the outer circle color of the points to black (or blue) to better show that the points are really there.

From [the Gadfly documentation](http://gadflyjl.org/themes.html) it seems like the `highlight_color` argument of `Theme()` might do that, but it takes a function as argument.

I don't understand how that is supposed to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't add a picture. This is a link: http://tinypic.com/r/9hu9f6/8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument name turns out to be `discrete_highlight_color`...

It should be a function that modifies the colour used for the plot,
typically by making it lighter (a "tint") or darker (a "shade").
In our case, we can just ignore the current colour and return black.

```
using Color
using Gadfly
plot(
  layer(
    x = sort(randn(1000),1), 
    y = sort(randn(1000),1), 
    Geom.point,
    # Theme(highlight_width=0.0mm) # To remove the border
    Theme( discrete_highlight_color = u -> LCHab(0,0,0) )
  ),
  layer(
    x = [-4,4], 
    y = [-4,4], 
    Geom.line(), 
    Theme(default_color=color("black"))
  )
)
```

[image: Scatterplot]

To find the correct argument, I first typed

```
code_lowered( Theme, () )
```

which gives the list of arguments,
and then

```
less( Gadfly.default_discrete_highlight_color )
```

which shows how the default value is defined.

Comment: Plus 1 for including how you got your solution. I think that's very helpful.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd the last line of code returns this error in Julia 0.6.3: `ERROR: function has multiple methods; please specify a type signature`, despite `using Gadfly` and passing a function. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd `Color` is incompatible with Julia 0.6.3 (`ERROR: Color can't be installed because it has no versions that support 0.6.3 of julia.`). I tried [`Colors`](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Colors.jl) and it works. It's just one character change, too small for me to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me trying to solve this problem more recently, I discovered that the best way to get rid of that pesky white ring is through the theme setting `highlight_width=0pt`

for example

```
plot(x=rand(10),y=rand(10),Theme(highlight_width=0pt))
```

I had some additional themes in the below image[image: an example I did]