# Outline around bars in bar plot in Gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995572/how-to-pass-a-function-to-julia-gadfly-theme-parameter) shows how to make the outline of points in a scatter plot black.

How can I make the outline of bars in a bar plot black? I have a white bar that will not show up with a white background. The following code does not provide a black outline around the bars.

```
    barplot = plot(df, x="Atom", y="E", 
          Geom.bar, Scale.x_discrete, 
          Guide.xlabel("Atom"), Guide.ylabel("Energy (kJ/mol)"),
          color=df[:Atom], Guide.colorkey("Atom"),
          Scale.color_discrete_manual(colors...),
          Theme(background_color=color("white"), 
                discrete_highlight_color = u -> LCHab(0,0,0))
          )
```

P.S. colors is an array of e.g. `RBG(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)` values.

[image]

Comment: Diving deep into the `Gadfly` code, there seems to be no current provision for drawing the outline of a bar.  Perhaps filing a new [Gadfly Issue](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues) describing what you want will get some notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Theme(bar_highlight=color("dark grey"))
```

Issue created and solved.
https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/571