# How to easily plot background vertical bands?

Tags: julia, gadfly

In Stata I can easily add bands in the background, e.g. to signal a period of recession:

```
clear
set obs 2
gen year = 1990
replace year = 2000 if _n == 2
gen x = 0
replace x = 1 if _n == 2

twoway ///
    (scatteri 1 `=' 1995 1 `=' 1996, bcolor(gs10) recast(area) lwidth(none)) ///
    (line x year)
```

The result is an increasing line with a background vertical band:

[image: Background vertical bands in Stata]

In Julia with Gadfly, the best I could find was contrived:

```
using Gadfly, DataFrames, Colors

df = DataFrame(year = [1990; 2000], x = [0; 1], color = [1; 1])

x_shade = [1995 1995 1996 1996]
y_shade = [0 1 1 0]

theme = Theme(
    discrete_highlight_color = u -> ARGB(1, 1, 1, 0),
    default_color = colorant"grey")

p = plot(
    layer(
        x = x_shade,
        y = y_shade,
        Geom.polygon(preserve_order = true, fill = true),
        order = 1
    ),
    layer(df,
          y = "x",
          x = "year",
          color = "color",
          Geom.line,
          order = 2
          ),
    theme
)
```

The result is similar to Stata:

[image: Background vertical bands in Julia with Gadfly]

To remove the stroke, I gave the theme a function that returns a transparent white (as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995572/how-to-pass-a-function-to-julia-gadfly-theme-parameter)). I was unable to set the fill of the band, so I set the default color to grey and added a dummy field `color` to change the color of the line plot from grey to another color. I also gave the y-coordinates of the vertical band from the maximum and minimum of the data, which may not coincide with the maximum and minimum of the viewport.

Does someone know of a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the discussion on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/1174#issuecomment-404276855), one contributor suggested `Geom.rect`, which requires adding a minimum and a maximum for the y axis:

```
using Gadfly, DataFrames

df = DataFrame(year = [1990; 2000], x = [0; 1], color = [1; 1])

recessions = DataFrame(peaks = [1995],
                       troughs = [1996],
                       ymin = minimum(df[:x]),
                       ymax = maximum(df[:x]))

plot(
    recessions,
    xmin = :peaks,
    xmax = :troughs,
    ymin = :ymin,
    ymax = :ymax,
    Geom.rect,
    Theme(default_color = colorant"grey"),
    layer(df,
          y = "x",
          x = "year",
          Geom.line,
          order = 2,
          Theme(default_color = colorant"black")
          )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

With Plots.jl you can just add a `vspan`, e.g.:

```
vspan([1995, 1996], linecolor = :grey, fillcolor = :grey)
plot!(df[:year], df[:x])
```

Comment: Yes, this works with `Plots.jl`. What about Gadfly.jl?

Answer (score 0):

This would require a non-trivial work.

You can base off [Geom.vline](http://gadflyjl.org/latest/gallery/geometries.html#[Geom.hline](@ref),-[Geom.vline](@ref)-1), where you would need to create something like `VBandGeometry` (like [VLineGeometry](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/3071ad661d7ca248105d472da7aa048d3fe46d6f/src/geom/hvabline.jl#L61)), and specify how to build the band (like [`render(::VLineGeometry)`](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/3071ad661d7ca248105d472da7aa048d3fe46d6f/src/geom/hvabline.jl#L83)), getting the limits correctly at [`Compose`](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/3071ad661d7ca248105d472da7aa048d3fe46d6f/src/geom/hvabline.jl#L52)